# How do I make Guake use my Zsh command history?

Tags: command-line, zsh, guake

I often use Guake (drop-down terminal for GNOME). The problem is that it apparently stores its own command history, and it is different from that of the standard  GNOME terminal. My shell is `zsh` and it is configured to store its command history in `~/.zsh_history`. How do I make `Guake` use the command history stored in `~/.zsh_history`?

Comment: Could you [edit] to clarify this? Maybe you could give an example or two of what is happening in the different emulators?

Comment: Well, I set zsh as a shell from Guake and it did the trick. Should I provide this as an answer or could you delete my question?

Comment: I think [egmont's answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/987083/how-do-i-make-guake-use-my-zsh-command-history/987085#987085) gave the explanation that led to that. I suggest accepting that answer and perhaps commenting on it to say that you set Guake to use Zsh and that fixed it. But if you can edit your question with any details of the previous set up that could help :)

Comment: No, it didn't. I figured it out on my own.

Comment: Well regardless of what you were thinking, which is none of my business, I was observing that the answer says "it could be that... Guake launches a different shell, eg Bash" - this was indeed the case, so the answer is correct

Comment: No problem, I will mark it it as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Guake` is a terminal emulator. As such, it doesn't store the command history anywhere (it doesn't even have a clue what a command history is). It launches your shell, and the shell does the rest.

It could be that, for whatever reason, `Guake` launches a different shell, e.g. `bash` instead of your preferred `zsh`. It could also be that it launches `zsh` with some different settings, e.g. different `argv[0]` which causes `zsh` to behave differently (e.g. `bash` behaves differently if you start it as `sh`; not sure if `zsh` has something like this too).

Another explanation could be that when `Guake` hides its window it doesn't terminate the shell running inside, the same `zsh` keeps running there and is shown you again when you invoke `Guake` again. That is, `zsh` did not write its history in between and did not read what other `zsh` instances wrote there (exactly as if it was a "regular" terminal emulator whose window you minimized but didn't close).

Comment: The trick is to set up Guake to use zsh shell. When you have `zsh` set as a default shell and Guake uses `<default_shell` this won't work.

Answer (score 1):

In your terminal, type 'guake'. When Guake launches, right click and click on preferences then click locate shell tab. On the shell tab, select /usr/bin/zsh. This will set your default shell to zsh, subsequently storing your code to zshrc_history. I hope this helps!

Comment: Even after setting the correct shell, you need to exit Guake (not just close the window) in order for the new history items to appear in the terminal. As long as Guake is still running, you won't see the new items in terminal.